# I am very new to API. Please send me what -H mean?

Tags: node.js, api

> curl -X POST https://api.commerce.coinbase.com/charges/ \
>   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>   -H "X-CC-Api-Key: YOUR_API_KEY" \
>   -H "X-CC-Version: 2018-03-22" \
>   -d "@data.json"

how do i make this api work?

Comment: How is this related to Node JS?

Answer (score 2):

-H attaches a header to your request. [See manpage of curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H).

Answer (score 0):

The -H is adding a Header to the request so everything between the speech marks after the -H is a header.

Your CURL request has 3 headers.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Request_header